# Need help on a Navigation Drawer transition

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I set up a navigation drawer, first it shows in the ocCreate method a Google Map. I would like to press another button in the navigation drawer menu and change the map fragment.

I have an activity_nav.xml with an app_bar_nav.xml which include the content_nav.xml.

I followed the google maps api site in order to implement the map and the navigation drawer part on google developers.

Now I'm stuck here because I don't know how to switch to another fragment inside the same nav drawer.

My content_nav.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".NavActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_nav">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".NavActivity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My onCreate() method:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

        /*Update the UI with user info*/

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        TextView email = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.navEmail);
        email.setText(user.getEmail());

        TextView name = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.navUsername);
        name.setText(user.getDisplayName());

        //Setup Map
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

The switching function:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the home action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

            mAuth.signOut();
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor Ed = sp.edit();
            Ed.putString("Email", null);
            Ed.putString("Password", null);
            Ed.apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you set the OnClickListener of your items ? If you did, do you enter the onNavigationItemSelected() method when you click on an item from drawer menu ?

Comment: Hi matdev, yes I did. The onNavigationItemSelected is posted in my original post. The method is working and i can handle the user click in the menu list. The problem is that I don't want to call a new activity, I would like to change the fragment (which currently is a google maps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch between fragments, your activity's layout should have a container layout:

```
 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your activity's onCreate() method, replace the container with the default fragment i.e. the map fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mapFragment).commit();
```

Then in onNavigationItemSelected(), replace the current fragment with the target fragment of the chosen item:

```
Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, YourTargetFragment.class.getName().getTitle());
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
setTitle(item.getTitle());
```

Comment: Ok thanks matdev. But, in your example, mapFragment how is defined? Is it a class? a layout? Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried this: SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it. Thanks to matdev :)

I followed your suggestion, basically the issue was related to the fragment I inserted in the content_nav.xml
I replaced the fragment with a FrameLayout, then I initialize the map with a SupportMapFragment. For the other fragments I will need I will create a class with a dedicated  xml for each.

I didn't understand this mechanics but your hint has been precious.

Comment: Glad to hear that !